# can't read string from file in c

Tags: c, fopen, scanf

I'm trying to read a text file line by line and printing the first 17 characters.

```
FILE *devices;
devices = NULL;
devices = fopen("devices.txt", "r");

char deviceaddr[17];
char addr[17];

char line[1024];

while (fgets(line,1024,devices) != NULL)
{
    fscanf(devices,"%s", deviceaddr);

    printf("%s\n", deviceaddr);
}

fclose(devices);
```

the output should be `00:07:80:4C:0E:EE`for the first line but it gives `6`.

Comment: Are you sure you meant C++? This is pure C.

Comment: This is much more C than C++. C++ would use `std::ifstream`, read using `while (std::getline)`, and take the first 17 characters with `.substr()`.

Comment: When working with fixed-size arrays, do not forget the trailing '\0'.

Comment: Do you mean print the first 17 characters of each line?

Comment: @hmjd no. i only get symbols and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way the output can be `"00:07:80:4c:0E:EE"`, since
that would result in undefined behavior, due to buffer
overrun—the string requires 18 bytes, but you only provide
17.  You should *never* us `"%s"` in an `fscanf` without
specifying the length.

And you're calling `fscanf` on `devices` after having read
a line from it; if you're reading line by line, you want to use
`sscanf` on the line you've read.

Answer (score 3):

The `while` loop is reading a line of text, then the `fscanf` will read the next set of text (and possibly overrun that buffer incidentally).  It seems as if you should just be printing the desired data inside the loop from the buffer `line`.

For example, suppose there are three lines of text.

```
00:07:80:4C:0E:EE    --> ends up line buffer line
second               --> ends up in deviceaddr
third line           --> ends up in line (unless the fscanf did not consume newline)
```

Comment: I'm trying to read line by line. this code works to read ints from file instead of a string.

Comment: If it uses the same logic (fgets followed by fscanf) then it would for sure skip the first line of text.  If the fscanf does not consume the newline, then the fgets would effectively be reading the newline character each time after each fscanf call.  So it might work "as desired" aside from "discarding" the first line.